# Top users feature of SE intermittently shows user with same ID from another SE site

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackexchange-2.0, reputation-leagues

**Steps to duplicate**

*This is highly intermittent and can change with no deterministic pattern that I can see.*

1. Navigate to https://stackexchange.com/leagues/21/week/mathematics/
2. Observe user list, make a note
3. Refresh page, observe user list for changes
4. Repeat 3 until you see a user change occur

**Expected output**

Here is an image showing the *correct* display (Rank #9):

[image]

[Vivi](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/85/vivi) is user 85 on math.SE, [Grace Note](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/85/) is user 85 on gaming.SE.

Answer (score 2):

Should be fixed now:

> I wasn't including the site in the cache key, so the same ID on other sites would get the cached version from the wrong site

Comment: I totally called this!